# Spring SFTP Integration Session write method

Tags: java, spring, sftp, spring-integration

Hi guys just want to ask if the the write method guarantees that the file has been successfully sent if it completes without an exception.

I was not able ro find the answer in the API documents.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/session/Session.html#write%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29

In my own testing I have never encountered a corrupted file when the write method completes without exception but is that always the case?

Or do I need to do other test like reading back the files I sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter uses the `FTPClient` from `apache commons-net` so it's whatever guarantees that it provides but, in general, I think you are safe if you get no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP client library typically only propagates any error it gets from the SFTP server, in addition to connection related errors that the library detects locally. So it's equally (if not more) important, what guaranties does the SFTP server give that the file was successfully saved, when the server returns no error. And that would obviously be implementation-specific.

Comment: Hi thanks to your reply, so is it suggested that i read back the file to ensure that I was able to deliver it in the first place? From what I understand from your answer there is no guaranties

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you cannot expect any guaranties from a client library, because it relies on a server in the first place. In general, I would be happy with not getting any exception. Though obviously reading the file back is the only 100% solution.